# how to place pin on specific latiutude and longitude on google map iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have an Iframe to show a map on a webpage like this,

```
if (browsername== "IE")

            sbOutput.AppendFormat("<iframe width=\"450\" height=\"250\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" align=\"bottom\" src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?key=ABQIAAAAyzfPKfpu4h_2V2EY0MQKcBQLL4oEiRrONF_Oyv5y1AbK0VEmMxQN1Z5_-BmLvlLLFYiLTknmwufmIg&amp;mapclient=jsapi&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&amp;spn=0.222565,0.596008&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed;\"></iframe>");

        else
            sbOutput.AppendFormat("<div><object data=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?key=ABQIAAAAyzfPKfpu4h_2V2EY0MQKcBQLL4oEiRrONF_Oyv5y1AbK0VEmMxQN1Z5_-BmLvlLLFYiLTknmwufmIg&amp;mapclient=jsapi&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&amp;spn=0.222565,0.596008&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed\"  width=\"450\" height=\"250\" > Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object></div>");
```

How do i get to place a pin on that specific latitude and longitude? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: google map have a api to do that. if i am not thing wrong you need this http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/chart-types-for-map-pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding q=latitude,longitude in the link will show the pin in the map along with the text box which shows the address.

Comment: I get two pins, one green with the GPS coordinates and one round red pin with a nearby district. If only there were a way to rename the pin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery plugin: http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);  
    var myOptions = {  
      zoom: 8,  
      center: latlng,  
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
    };  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  myOptions);
```